# Can't Use Default Spacing Options on Tailwind

Tags: css, laravel, tailwind-css

I've just started a new project in Laravel but I'm having issues with Tailwind. I can't use all `margin` or `padding` spacing options like `m-5`, `p-4` or `mb-4` and so on... Weird thing is I can use `mt-5` but can't use `m-5`.

When I create a new project, it comes with Tailwind CSS. I also tried with npm installation with `npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest` but nothing changed.

Checkout this image: [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/1f5n605).

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: How can we know what it is wrong if you are not sharing how are you loading TailwindCSS ? Are you using Mix ? Are you loading through a CDN link ? Add information please as it is basic for resolving issues...

Comment: You need to show us your code

Comment: @matiaslauriti When I create a new project, it comes with Tailwind CSS. I also tried with npm installation with `npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest` but nothing changed. I'm facing the same problem with new projects also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The new JIT (Just In Time) feature was enabled by default. I removed `mode: 'jit',` line in `tailwind.config.js` and compiled again. And problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think remove mode: 'jit' is a good idea. alternate for dev mode you can whitelist all class like this:

```
$ npm install dotenv --save
```

ADD this line and code to your tailwind.config.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

Define PURGE variable in .env

```
safelist: process.env.PURGE === "development" ? [{ pattern: /.*/ }] : []
```

Here is full article about it.
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/6557